# Couldn't convert user input from html and search in sql database

Tags: php, sql, html, mysqli

Consider user input as: α-hemolysin

The same I have stored in the database as html entity `&alpha;-hemolysin`.

But when I am converting the user input using `htmlentities()`, I get modified input like `&#945-hemolysin`, which cannot be searched in the database.

I need to convert the user input as same as stored in the database like `&alpha;-hemolysin`

Is there any way to get all possible html entities (named, numerical, unicode) and search for all in sql database.

PHP line:

```
$input='α-hemolysin';
$v=htmlentities($input);
echo $v;
```

Output:

```
&#945-hemolysin
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not save data in database with html entities. It just makes things difficult, as can be seen here. Only store proper data.

Comment: Please show your input code. I've tried your code in PHP using a pre-defined `$input` variable and using your input and it outputs correctly. I think I know what's the issue but need to verify.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I tried to save the data in as it is in sql database. Many characters went unsupported. So converted to the htmlentities. Can you suggest some ideas to handle special characters while storing the sql database.

Comment: Make sure the database is in a mode that allows Unicode data and you handle everything as such. Then there isn’t a character you can’t handle. Of course PHP and Unicode are a different thing, but there’s plenty of articles and tutorials on how to make it work.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I will check that.

Comment: @Lachie I edited the code